# multiple modules with same name in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using **Angular 7**

I have modulerized the application and having two modules **Admin** and **Technician**.

Each module have **Dashboard** module with following directory structure

```
- app
  - admin
    - dashboard
      - dashboard.module.ts
      - dashboard.routing.ts
  - technician
    - dashboard
      - dashboard.module.ts
      - dashboard.routing.ts
```

But this gives error as

```
ERROR in NaNbut they point to different modules 
"(/../app/admin/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts and "/../app/technician/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts"). 
Webpack cannot distinguish on context and would fail to load the proper one.
```

**Is there a way I can have modules with same name?**

Comment: Where is the error given? Which line?

Comment: It is not in a particular line, instead in the console when starting the server and while compiling.

Comment: It's an ongoing issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10128

Comment: do you import both on the app.module and app-routing? If yes then I would advise to create and admin module and a technician module(both for routing as well). Then import each dashboard to the correct routing module(admin and techinician

Comment: No, not both in the app module. They both are called in routing from two different modules. They are never together in any module.